# How to Ignore or Stop Repeating of Random Numbers in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form.

When client submit the form I am sending a invoice to his email and to our site email(info@example.com).

I am Generating a random number to every invoice when client submit the form. The Invoice number is look like `#502689`.

So for that I am using Php random function like rand(99,999999). I don't want to repeat this random number again.

Two days back I got a Invoice number like #125459 and after two days when another client submitted the form then again I got the invoice number as `#125459`.

So how can I Ignore the repeating of this random number. Please help me.

Comment: What an odd way to create invoices. You'll need to save the invoice numbers in a database and check for their existence.

Comment: use guid, not random numbers. https://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Comment: Provided that the invoice number is **not** the invoice database ID then why not just use incrementing numbers? A GUID is not helpful as an invoice number needs to be human readable. Start with a number such as #10000 and incremement by 1 for each invoice - that way they're all unique, human readable and they're different to the invoice database ID, which I imagine would begin at 0.

Comment: As @KallumTanton said: Save the invoice no. in a database starting from a higher number. Additionally, make sure it only exists once => Your DB column has to be UNIQUE.

Comment: @Mahmood Mohammed may be you should use `mktime()`, function related to date and time, so the repeatation chances are very less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Best method it will be to use increment id. For example if you use mysql you can set to primary key if it's int to be autoincrement. So eveytime when you create a new invoice it will generate next id => no duplicates.
2. If you want to use random id's you will have to keep retying to generate invoice number until current invoice number is not used. For this you can use a code like this:

   ```
   do {
       $invoice_id = rand(99, 99999);
       if(invoice number already exists) { //Use your code here to check if number is unique.
           $ok = false; //Invoice number is used. try again a new number
       } else {
           $ok = true; //Invoice number is not used
       }
   } while(!$ok)
   ```
3. If you don't generate more than 1 invoice / second you can use time() as id (unixtimestamp in seconds). But if you generate 2 invoice in same second this will not help you.
4. If you don't want to be numberic you can use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)() method of php.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to check against your existing invoice numbers, that's what @daniel-dudas' solution also implies. I would recommend the auto incremental database solution as well.

Btw, you should furthermore consider that in some countries, you are forced by law to give invoice numbers constantly increasing, not randomly.